# type mismatch compiler error when concatenating two maps using getOrElse

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, type-mismatch

I'm trying to concatenate a mutable with an immutable map in scala.

```
case class Result(val key: String, val number: Int)

object Test extends App {

  val map1 = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, List[Result]]()
  val map2: Map[String, List[Result]] = Map("test" -> List(new Result("0", 0)))

  map1 ++= map2.map(c => (c -> (c._2 + map1.getOrElse(c._1, List[Result]()))))

}
```

But compiler always says:

```
type mismatch;  found   : List[Result]  required: String
```

When i change ListResult to "test" compiler says:

```
type mismatch;  found   : java.io.Serializable  required: String
```

I'm quite confused. Do I use getOrElse the wrong way?

regards
Cyrill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
map1 ++= map2.map(c => (c -> (c._2 + map1.getOrElse(c._1, List[Result]()))))
```

map on a Map gets passed each element of the Map. So c is a `(String, List[Result])`.  So this

```
(c -> (c._2 + map1.getOrElse(c._1, List[Result]()))
```

is ((String, List[Result), (List[Result]). Which is wrong. I imagine you meant

```
(c._1 -> (c._2 + map1.getOrElse(c._1, List[Result]()))
```

but that still has a type mismatch. I think you're hitting the fairly common problem of the implicit Any2String for +, and the compiler wants a String where it shouldn't.

Anyway,

```
(c._1 -> (c._2 ++ map1.getOrElse(c._1, List[Result]()))
```

seems to work

```
map1 ++= map2.map(c => (c._1 -> (c._2 ++ map1.getOrElse(c._1, List[Result]()))))
```

Also, Nil is a bit neater:

```
map1 ++= map2.map(c => (c._1 -> (c._2 ++ map1.getOrElse(c._1, Nil))))
```

and clearer again (IMO) is the for comprehension

```
for ((k,v) <-map2) map1 += (k-> (v ++ map1.getOrElse(k, Nil)))
```